# How can I correct the Meteor base-url in a NginX reverse-proxy configuration?

Tags: javascript, nginx, reverse-proxy, meteor, base-url

I have installed both Apache and Meteor behind NginX through reverse-proxy (on an Ubuntu server). Apache is mapped directly as baseURL (www.mydomain.com/) and Meteor is mapped as a subfolder (www.mydomain.com/live/).

The problem I encounter is that my Meteor test (which works as expected at port 3000) stops working behind NginX since every single references (CSS, Javascript, template) are absolute to baseURL.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/live.css?abc">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore/underscore.js?efg"></script>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/template.live.js?hij"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/live.js?klm"></script>
</head>
```

Obviously, since Apache is mapped at baseURL, these files are not found when testing through NginX.

What would be the best way to resolve to problem? System Administration is not my forte, and Meteor is my first incursion at server-side javascript. So I don't even know if this can be fixed, and if so, if it's done through a server configuration, Meteor configuration or programmatically.

---

EDIT: The new "absolute-url" package in Meteor 0.4.0 fixed the problem!

http://docs.meteor.com/#absoluteurl

Comment: As this is more a server-based problem you might your question a better fit at [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @adamjansch - I'll give it a try, but since the Meteor devs are using [StackOverflow](http://www.meteor.com/join-us) as a way to receive feedback and interact with developers, I figured it was (and still is) the best way to go at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new "absolute-url" package in Meteor 0.4.0 fixed the problem.

http://docs.meteor.com/#absoluteurl

Comment: This no longer applies as the package has been deprecated in favor Meteor.absoluteUrl() and the "ROOT_URL" env variable. I've tried setting "ROOT_URL", and although it does change the urls that Meteor.absoluteUrl produces, it seems to have no effect on the url that Meteor uses for including the application's js file (when running the bundled version).

Comment: Have the exact same problem, though the question is a bit outdated. How do you currently solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you including scripts and styles in your `<head>` with Meteor?  Anything included within your meteor project directory, be it js, html or css, will get bundled up and served to the client without being included in your HTML with `<link>` and `<script>`.

If you must include things in your `<head>`, why not just use the absolute path including the subfolder?

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/live/live.css?abc">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/live/packages/underscore/underscore.js?efg"></script>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/live/template.live.js?hij"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/live/live.js?klm"></script>
</head>
```

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: I'm not including those scripts myself... they are included automatically by Meteor. I used the ?abc URL params in my example instead of the convoluted ones generated by Meteor (ie. ?078ed06e57d7119bc9e3386e8a5ccebc236b0042) for easy readability. My mistake.