# How to run meteor from a route different from root (behind nginx proxy)?

Tags: nginx, meteor

I have a meteor app running on port 3000

now `http://1.2.3.4:3000` works as expected.

I'm trying to run expose the meteor app as a directory outside of the document root, so on the same box, I have nginx running on port 80 configured like so:

```
server {

  ...

  server_name my.test.com

  ...

  location /meteor{
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000;
  }

  ...

}
```

Now when I load `http://1.2.3.4/meteor` I get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
__meteor_runtime_config__ = {"ROOT_URL":"meteor","serverId":"ABC12345"};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/26b7ea5a393eddd33c2278e17dc1d537732e9553.js"></script>
```

Noe that it's trying to include js from the root route **src="/26b7e...** so it's failing.

I've found some information suggesting that the ROOT_URL env variable needs to be set. I've set that to "meteor", which is the name of my route in nginx but it doesn't seem to affect the behaviour of this. I think that variable only changes how Meteor.absoluteUrl works.

How do I tell meteor where to include its resources from? I don't want to run meteor on the root / route.

Comment: This appears to duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936242/how-can-i-correct-the-meteor-base-url-in-a-nginx-reverse-proxy-configuration

Comment: @konrad it sure is! - I actually hadn't seen that one, but the answer no longer applies as that package they mention has been deprecated. The ROOT_URL doesn't seem to affect where the app js gets included from. I've traced it all the way in and it appears "/" is hard coded

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this wasn't supported before Meteor 0.6.5.

The following was added on v0.6.5+

> ROOT_URL may now have a path part. This allows serving multiple Meteor
>   apps on the same domain.

So setting the ROOT_URL environment variable enables the behaviour I was looking for.