# Multiple Meteor sites behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, meteor

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936242/how-can-i-correct-the-meteor-base-url-in-a-nginx-reverse-proxy-configuration) SO question, but the recommended solution in the comments to use Meteor.absoluteUrl() doesn't seem to be working as expected. I want to be able to deploy multiple meteor applications to the same server and use nginx as a reverse proxy to each application.

Because each application is segregated none of the applications are going to be accessible from the ROOT_URL, but Meteor is only using the ROOT_URL to reference back for the assets it needs to load a meteor app.

I tried appending to the address using Meteor.absoluteUrl() in the server's startup, the client's startup function, and outside of the client's startup function.  It had no affect in any of these places.

For example. I have nginx listening at /site1 for server_name: example.com and a reverse proxy to port 3001 to my meteor application.

When going to the site it initially loads fine but the browser dev tool shows Meteor is trying to find the javascript and css files at https://example.com when it should be looking from a base url of https://example.com/site1

Meteor.absoluteUrl("site1",{ssl:true}) was set in Meteor.startup() to try and force that as the correct path.  As you can see, I am only appending to ROOT_URL with no leading / as described in the Meteor documentation.

I'm using meteor up to deploy and here's how the mup.json environment settings look:

"env": {
        "ROOT_URL": "https://example.com",
        "PORT": 3001,
        "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/db"
    }

Any clarification about this this should work is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you do it with subdomains rather than path prefixes?

Comment: That seems possible but I would think there's a bit of flexibility somehow with Meteor in this situation?   I guessing I'd have to setup an additional server configuration for each subdomain in the nginx vhost configuration. I  just may try this if all else fails.

Comment: Think how you're going to handle client side routing with those path prefixes. If `iron:router` does not include that as an options it will probably be a nightmare.

Comment: This is a related issue: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/154

Comment: Sounds like a related problem; however, I want to deploy multiple meteor applications to the same physical server and access them all from a single secured port (443) as opposed to having a single Meteor application serving multiple routes. Iron-router may not be involved since that's route management within a single Meteor application...right?

Answer (score 1):

Using sub-domains suggested by apendua seems to be the easiest way to accommodate multiple Meteor applications on the same server behind nginx (if you that option available to you).

1. Register a sub-domain for each application (i.e. app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com, etc.)
2. Add an nginx server configuration for each sub-domain, setting the server_name property to your sub-domain address.
3. Add a default location for that server and set your proxy_pass to http://127.0.0.1:port where port is the port number you set in your environment configuration when you deployed your Meteor application (in my case I set this in my mup.json).

Answer (score 0):

The root url for public assets under a meteor app is actually at `/public`. Each of your apps has a different base directory for the app. Assuming that you have an overall structure that looks like:

```
app1/ - nginx maps to https://example1.com/
  client/
  lib/
  public/
  server/
app2/ - nginx maps to https://example2.com/
  client/
  lib/
  public/
  server/
etc...
```

Then each app's *public* assets will just be under `Meteor.absoluteUrl()` which will serve files from `app/public`. `Meteor.absoluteUrl()+"app1"` has no meaning.

Comment: Hi Michel.  mup (meteor up) publishes the application to /opt/<appName>/app and the assets are residing under /opt/<appName>/app/programs/web.browser.  How do I configure Meteor to use http://domain.com/appAlias1 to get to the assets if I have nginx properly setup as a reverse proxy to the actual meteor application port? appAlias1, in this case is a vhost setup in the nginx configuration pointing internally to app1 listening on the Meteor port (i.e. 3000). Thx

Comment: I'm not sure you can reconfigure Meteor to serve the assets from a different subdirectory. It serves the merged/minified css and js files from root (/) as a virtual path. You'll probably have to dig into the meteor source code to figure this out. Question is, why do you need to? Why does the normal nginx configuration not work for you? Should you be running your meteor apps on different ports?

Comment: I'm not so sure the problem is with nginx. It's the inability to get Meteor to extend the absolute url it uses to get back to it's assets, which just so happens to be a url that is reverse proxied through nginx. In this case the extension is necessary to separate multiple meteor applications on the same physical server.  Each Meteor app is listening on a separate port.  But externally all users use the same port 443 with the aliased application name to get to the internal Meteor application using the proxy setup for each nginx location. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I believe so. I presume you've read David Weldon's post on nginx + Meteor? He knows more than I.